# Webpack won't minify js files in sub-folder

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, uglifyjs

Webpack runs (to some extent). It finishes the run. There is one error (see below) which many online have explained about.

ERROR in koLabs.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ()) [./~/source-map-loader!./Labs/labsCtrl.js:512,0]

But, it minifies only select js files mainly in the top folder. It leaves out files in the sub-folder without any minification.

/Scripts/Tomat0 - works
/Scripts/Tomat0/(sub-folders) - doesn't minify

Any thoughts on it.

My Webpack:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');

const merge = require("webpack-merge");

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const WebpackAutoInject = require('webpack-auto-inject-version');

var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

//const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const PATHS = 
{
    scripts: path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts'),
    mobile: path.join(__dirname, "mobile/js"),
    Tomat0: path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts/Tomat0')
};

//console.log(__dirname);
//console.log(PATHS.scripts);

module.exports = 
{
    //context:    path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/Tomat0/Account'),
    noInfo: false,
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: 
    {
        vendorReact: 
        [
            // path.resolve("./mobile/css/Tomat0-css.js"),

            //"react", "react-dom", 
            "jquery", "jQuery-ui",
            "inputmask",
            "bootstrap", "moment", "moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt",
            "knockout", "knockout.mapping", "sammy"
            //,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")
            , path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
        ],

        // vendorKO: 
        // [
        //     "jquery", "bootstrap", "moment", 
        //     "knockout", "knockout.mapping", "sammy"
        //     ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
        //     ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
        //     ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")
        //     ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
        // ],

        login:  
        [
            // "react", "react-dom",
            "bootstrap", "moment", "jQuery-ui"
            ,"moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt"
            //path.resolve("./mobile/css/Tomat0-css.js"),
            ,"jsbridge"
            //,path.resolve('./Scripts/javascriptBridge.js')
            //,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jtsage-datebox.bootstrap.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jtsage-datebox.i18n.es-ES.utf8.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jtsage-datebox.i18n.pt-BR.utf8.min.js")

            // ,'commonControls.js'

            // ,'accountCreateReact.js'
            // ,'personalInfoReact.js'
            // ,'loginReact.js'

            ,path.resolve('./Account/commonControls.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/accountCreateReact.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/personalInfoReact.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/loginReact.tsx')
        ],

        account:  
        [
            // "react", "react-dom",
            "bootstrap", "moment", "jQuery-ui",
            "moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt",
            //"jsbridge",

            //path.resolve("./mobile/css/Tomat0-css.js"),

            //path.resolve("./Scripts/maskedinput-1.4.js"),

            // path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
             path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jtsage-datebox.bootstrap.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jtsage-datebox.i18n.es-ES.utf8.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jtsage-datebox.i18n.pt-BR.utf8.min.js")

            //,path.resolve("./Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js")
            //,path.resolve("./Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js")

            //,path.resolve('./Scripts/javascriptBridge.js')
            //, path.resolve("./Scripts/masked_input_1.4.js")

            ,path.resolve('./Account/commonControls.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/accountCreateReact.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/personalInfoReact.tsx')

            ,path.resolve('./Account/dforReact.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/surranReact.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/associations.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/permissions.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/invitation.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/notes.tsx')
            , path.resolve('./Account/seneg.tsx')
            , path.resolve('./Account/AddGN.tsx')
            ,path.resolve('./Account/account.tsx')

            ,path.resolve('./Account/MHT.tsx')

            ,path.resolve('./Account/minders.tsx')

            // ,'commonControls.js'

            // ,'accountCreateReact.js'
            // ,'personalInfoReact.js'
            // ,"dforReact.js"           
            // ,"surranReact.js"        
            // ,"associations.js"          
            // ,"permissions.js"           
            // ,"invitation.js"            
            // ,"notes.js"                 

            // ,"account.js"

            // ,"MHT.js"
        ],

        komds:
        [
            "bootstrap", "moment", //"knockout", "knockout.mapping", "sammy", 
            "moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt",

//"jquery",
            //path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"),

             path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")

            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Account/_partialLoginPopup.js")

            //,path.resolve("./sbal/sbalCtrl.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mds/mdsCtrl.js")
        ],

        kosbal:
        [
            "bootstrap", "moment", //"knockout", "knockout.mapping", "sammy", 
            "moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt",

             path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")

            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Account/_partialLoginPopup.js")

            ,path.resolve("./sbal/sbalCtrl.js")
        ],

        koAsh:
        [
            "bootstrap", "moment", //"knockout", "knockout.mapping", "sammy", 
            "moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt",

             path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")

            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Account/_partialLoginPopup.js")

            ,path.resolve("./Ash/AshModel.ts")
            ,path.resolve("./Ash/AshCtrl.ts")
            // ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Ash/AshModel.js")
            // ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Ash/AshCtrl.js")
        ],

        kosol:
        [
            "bootstrap", "moment", //"knockout", "knockout.mapping", "sammy", 
            "moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt",

             path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")

            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Account/_partialLoginPopup.js")

            ,path.resolve("./sol/solModel.ts")
            ,path.resolve("./sol/solCtrl.ts")
            // ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/sol/solModel.js")
            // ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/sol/solCtrl.js")
        ],

        kovacat:
        [
            "bootstrap", "moment", //"knockout", "knockout.mapping", "sammy", 
            "moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt",

             path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")

            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Account/_partialLoginPopup.js")

            ,path.resolve("./vacat/vacatModel.ts")
            ,path.resolve("./vacat/vacatCtrl.ts")
            // ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Vacctnes/vacatModel.js")
            // ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/vacat/vacatCtrl.js")
        ],

        koVitals:
        [
            "bootstrap", "moment", //"knockout", "knockout.mapping", "sammy", 
            "moment/locale/es", "moment/locale/pt",

             path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.fittext-1.1.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js")
            ,path.resolve("./mobile/js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.js")

            ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Account/_partialLoginPopup.js")

            ,path.resolve("./Vitals/vitalsModel.ts")
            ,path.resolve("./Vitals/vitalsCtrl.ts")
            // ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Vitals/vitalsModel.js")
            // ,path.resolve("./Scripts/Tomat0/Vitals/vitalsCtrl.js")
        ]

    },

    output: 
    {
        path: PATHS.Tomat0,
        filename: '[name].js'
        ,libraryTarget: 'var'
    },

    externals:
    {
        'react': 
        {
            "var": 'React',
            web: 'React',
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'React'
        },
        'react-dom': 
        {
            "var": 'ReactDOM',
            web: 'ReactDOM',
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'ReactDOM'
        }
    },

    plugins: 
    [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        ({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            jquery: "jquery",
        }),

        // new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        // ({
        //     Bootstrap: "bootstrap", 
        //     bootstrap: "bootstrap", 
        // }),        

        // new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        // ({
        //     moment: "moment", 
        // }),        

        // new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        // ({
        //     React: "react", 
        //     react: "react", 
        //     "window.react": "react", 
        //     "window.React": "react"
        // }),        

        // new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        // ({
        //     ReactDOM: "react-dom", 
        //     "react-dom": "react-dom", 
        //     "window.ReactDOM": "react-dom"
        // }),        

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        ({
            knockout: "knockout",
            ko: "knockout",
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        ({
            "knockout.mapping": "knockout.mapping",
            "ko.mapping": "knockout.mapping",
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        ({
            Sammy: "sammy",
            sammy: "sammy",
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin    //  This works
        ({
            typeahead: "corejs-typeahead",
            bloodhound: "corejs-typeahead",
            Bloodhound: "corejs-typeahead",
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin
            ({
                jsbridge: "javascriptBridge"
            }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin
            ({
                inputmask: "inputmask"
            }),

        //  DO NOT USE THESE - This version no longer works.

        // new webpack.ProvidePlugin
        // ({
        //     typeahead: path.resolve('./Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js'),
        //     Bloodhound: path.resolve('./Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js'),
        // }),

        //  NOTE: to augment the version, use switches --evn.major, env.minor, or --env.patch

        new WebpackAutoInject
        ({
            PACKAGE_JSON_PATH: './package.json',
            components: 
            {
                InjectAsComment: true
            },
            componentsOptions: 
            {
                InjectAsComment: 
                {
                    tag: 'Build version: {version} - {date}' // default 
                }
            }
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendorReact", /* filename= */"vendorReact.js", Infinity),

        //  DO NOT USE Multiple Plugins - does not yield correct results.

        // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin
        // (
        //     {
        //         names: ["vendorReact", "vendorKO"],  filename: "[name].js", minChunks: Infinity
        //     }
        // ),

        //  This is needed to prevent moment js from loading ALL locales - we only support three for now (en|es|pt)
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\\\/]locale$/, /^\.\/es$/, /^\.\/pt$/),
        //  Add a plug-in for straight copy of files from node_modules to Scripts directory for publishing from VS

        new CopyWebpackPlugin
        (
            [
                {from: './node_modules/react/dist/*.js', to: path.join(PATHS.scripts, 'react'), flatten: true},
                {from: './node_modules/react-dom/dist/*.js', to: path.join(PATHS.scripts, 'react'), flatten: true},
            ]
        ),

        // new webpack.DefinePlugin(
        // {
        //     'process.env': 
        //     {
        //         NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        //     }
        // }),

        // new ExtractTextPlugin
        // ({
        //     filename: "[name].css"
        // }),        

         new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(
         {
             //    compress: 
             //    {
             //        warnings: false,
             //    },
                 minimize: true,
                 output: 
                 {
                     comments: false,
                 },
         })
    ],

    // noParse: 
    // [
    //     ///[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]fittext[\/\\]dist[\/\\]jquery\.fittext\.js$/,
    //     path.join(PATHS.scripts, "typeahead.bundle.js")
    // ],

    resolve:
    {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.ts', 'tsx', 'css'],
        root: 
        [
            path.resolve('.'),
            path.resolve('./Scripts'),
            path.resolve('./Scripts/Tomat0/Account')
        ],
        alias: 
        {
            i18nextXHRBackend: "i18next-xhr-backend/i18nextXHRBackend.js",
            jsbridge: path.join(PATHS.scripts, "javascriptBridge.js"),
            inputmask: path.join(PATHS.scripts, "maskedinput-1.4.js"),

            //"jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js", 
            // Bloodhound: path.resolve('./Scripts/Bloodhound.js'),
            // typeahead: path.resolve('./Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js'),
            // ko: "knockout/build/output/knockout-latest.js",
            // "ko.mapping": "knockout.mapping/knockout.mapping.js",
            // Sammy: "sammy/lib/sammy.js",
        }
    },

    // modulesDirectories: 
    // [
    //     'node_modules',
    //     'Scripts'
    // ],

    module:
    {
        loaders:
        [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            //{test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/, loader: "ts-loader"},
            {test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"},  
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' },
            {test: /\.png$/, loader: "file-loader" },

//            {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader') },

            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader:"url?prefix=font/&limit=5000"},
            {test: /\.ttf$/,  loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
            {test: /\.eot$/,  loader: "file" },
            {test: /\.svg$/,  loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },   



            //  Does not work.
            // {
            //     test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            //     loader: 'expose-loader?jQuery!expose-loader?$'
            // },
        ],

        preLoaders: 
        [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                loader: "source-map-loader" 
            }
        ] 

    }
}
```

Comment: what does your webpack config look like?  are you telling it to look in those subdirs?

Comment: I updated my post with full webpack.config.js

Comment: We fixed the syntax error. It was caused by arrow function which is not handled by typescript well. We simple replace () => with function ().